# Running Twilio on azure website never sends sms

Tags: twilio, azure-web-app-service

Has anyone run into an issue trying to use Twilio on an mvc site deployed to azure websites?

The following code that works fine locally is always returning null on the website.

```
     var twilio = twilioRestClient.SendSmsMessage(
                "+12345",
                number,
                string.Format(
                    "Your registration verification code is: {0}",
                    code)
                );
```

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Can you check to see if an error is being returned from Twilio?  You can do this by checking the RestException property which is part of the SMSMessage object returned from the SendSmsMessage method.

In your case that would look like this:

```
if (twilio.RestException!=null) {
    //something bad happened
}
```

The RestException object will include properties you can use to figure out what happened.

If RestException is null, you can check the Twilio logs to see if we actually tried to send a message and failed by going here:

https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/sms

Hope that helps.

Devin

Comment: Hi Devin, Thanks for you're post. I did try that and the rest exception  is null and to make things harder to debug nothing is shown in the account portal. I've checked all the references are set to copy local and they are.